# A way to bypass the per-ip limit retrieving profile picture?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, limit

My app download all the user's friends pictures.

All the requests are of this kind:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<friend id>/picture?type=small
```

But, after a certain limit is reached, instead of the picture I get:

```
{"error""message":"(#4) Application request limit reached","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

Actually, the only way I found to prevent this is to change the server ip (manually). 
There isn't a better way?

Comment: I need to store the images server side, to create another images as a composition of each friends images. I download roughly 90000 images hourly per-IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record:

The limit is related to the Graph Api **only**, and the `graph.facebook.com/<user>/picture` url is a graph api call that returns a redirect.

So, to avoid the daily limit, simply fetch all the images url from FQL, like:

```
SELECT uid, pic_small, pic_big, pic, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid = me() or IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
```

now these are the direct urls to the images, for eg:

http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/275716_1546085527_622218197_q.jpg

so don't store them since they continuously change.

Answer (score 1):

If it's needed for an online app better way not to download those images, but use an online version, there is couple of reasons for doing so:

- Users change pictures (some frequently), do you need an updated version?
- Facebook's servers probably faster than yours and friends pictures probably cached within browser of your user.

**Update:**
Since limit you reach is [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) call limit, not the image retrieval, another solution that comes to my head just now is using [friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#friends) connection of [user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) in Graph API and specifying **picture** in **fields** argument, eq: `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=picture`, this will return direct URL-s for friends pictures so you can do only one call to get all needed info to download the images for every user...

Comment: Sadly I only download the pictures one time, then I cache it server side (What I do, is to create a composition of all the pictures and save it as another image)

However I have ~1000 users hourly, and 3 servers on Amazon Ec2, so 300 users per IP, with ~300 friends each,
ie 90000 images hourly per server

Comment: Then probably allocating new IP or spawning instances that will only be used to download images (spot instances may, or may not will be better for you) shouldn't be too hard, eq: you can allocate new Elastic IP from running instance itself, or you can use a simple download script that uses ec2 instance metadata to discover what should be downloaded. This can be done via command-line tools or via API..

Comment: The problem with elastic ip, is that often I get the same address (at least in eu west) and that I'm limited to 5 ip. Also for several reasons I'm forced to use Large instances (at least for the next days). For this reasons I'm more interested in a software solution, like a different way to obtain the picture full url, for example. Consider that I've started the app 3 day ago, and I'm already serving 10k daily users.